# How can i get tweet more than 10 days by using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I already use since but it doesn't work how can i config my code to get tweet more than 10 days or How can i take a data by using loop for 10 days , if i use 5 loop i can get data for 50 days

This is my code :

```
qw='#thaidrama'
ge=None
l=None
t=None
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=qw,g=ge, lang=l,since = '2017-11-14').items():
```

Comment: I believe they have a great documentation here http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/

Comment: Do you have an enterprise or premium Twitter account? If not, the [standard API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) specifies a 7-day limit.